# Training existing core nlp model

Tags: stanford-nlp

I want to train existing Stanford core-nlp's `english-left3words-distsim.bin` model with some more data which fits my use case. I want to assign custom tags for certain words like `run` will be a `COMMAND`.

Where can I get the training data set? I could follow something like [model training](https://medium.com/@klintcho/training-a-swedish-pos-tagger-for-stanford-corenlp-546e954a8ee7#.ss9952esm)

Answer (score 0):

For the most part it is sections 0-18 of the WSJ Penn Treebank.

Link: https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/ldc99t42

We have some extra data sets we don't distribute as well that we add on to the WSJ data.